# android browser, orientation bug using the back button

Tags: android, dom, screen-orientation

First of all, I did try 314 things to get this working...

I don't have this problem using iPhone/chrome, only with the android default browser.

- a user opens the android browser
- opens (in this example) my website in portrait mode
- presses the button "more info"
- on the new page the users turns the device in landscape mode
  everything works oke for now.
- the user hits the android browser back button (stays in landscape mode)

Error; everything is zoomed in now (showing big images and text).

Some other facts:

- I don't want the user to be able to zoom
- the website is made for mobile devices with this viewport setting

  ```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  ```
- I did try some viewport variations
- I did try a javascript script like this

  ```
  $(window).on('orientationchange', orientationChangeHandler);
  function orientationChangeHandler(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 2000);
  ```
- I did try dom onload `$(window).trigger('resize');`

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that just trying hundreds of random things to solve a problem might not be the best possible approach.

Comment: yes I know but that's desperation... and my last hope was here to ask the experts